# How do I detect a click event on a google maps PolyLine overlay?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

It seems to me that I should be able to do the following to detect a click event on a line on a google map:

```
var line = new GPolyline( ... );
map.addOverlay(line);
GEvent.addListener(line, "click", function(latlng){ alert("clicked"); });
```

The [api reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GPolyline.click) says this is available in version 2.88, which was released in 2007(!?), so I'm assuming that's what I'm using, but I don't know how to confirm that.

I also tried setting the `{clickable:true}` option explicitly (it's supposed to be the default.)  I've tested in FireFox 3 and Opera 9.6 so doubt it's browser specific.  I'm also using jQuery on the page.

I have plenty of code detecting clicks on markers that works fine, clicking on lines would be really nice, can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick test and the following code worked on my test page:

```
var polyline = new GPolyline([
  new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
  new GLatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)
], "#ff0000", 10);
map.addOverlay(polyline);

GEvent.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {
    alert('you clicked polyline');
});
```

The way to tell what version of google maps you have is to look at the v= parameter of the google maps src url you have

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=MY_API_KEY
```

In this case I have "v=2", that means I am using the latest stable 2 version, which supports clickable polylines (as of today 2.101 is the most recent release).  "v=2.x" means you are using an edge release. And any "v=2.5" where the anything after the period (.) is a number refers to a specific release

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info re the version, but I still don't really see how you're supposed to know what the "latest stable version" is...  A .version or .getVersion() on the GMap2 object wouldn't go astray.

Comment: No idea why, but today when I'm testing in Mozilla it's working (fresh test code, so there must have been a subtle difference somewhere...), but no luck in Opera.  Cheers for your help.

Comment: This is the closest place I found where you can figure out what v=2 and v=2.x are equal to

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/web/api-version-changes?pli=1

Answer (score 6):

Update: in version 3 of the API, you want to use `google.maps.event.addListener(object, event, function);`

e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {
    alert('you clicked polyline');
    });
```

For more details, see the [events api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for this!

1. lots of the GMarker click examples have the GEvent BEFORE the addListener(), which does not work I found.  reversing the order makes it work.
2. you can find your real version with alert(G_API_VERSION);

Using the stnadard src url above, my is:  // G_API_VERSION == 208a

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

GPolylines can be made clickable by adding a click event to them as with other objects (code taken from previous answer):

```
var polyline = new GPolyline([
  new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
  new GLatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)
], "#ff0000", 10);
map.addOverlay(polyline);

GEvent.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {
    alert('you clicked polyline');
});
```

However, you should also be aware that after the GPolyline event is raised, a click event on the map itself in the same location is raised. Additionally, there is currently a bug (as of Apr 2010) in this particular event as the event parameters do not properly get passed to the map click event. This is a known bug by Google and they are working to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it appears to not be possible to have click events within *Symbols* that are on a Polyline. Nor do they inherit the click events that are attached to the *Polyline* itself. More information here: [Google Maps: clickable polyline icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968898/google-maps-clickable-polyline-icon/16540858#16540858)